# Poisson process expected value

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let {${N(t), t \geq0}$} be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Let $S_n$ denote the time of the $nth$ event. What is $E[N(4)-N(2)|N(1)=3]$?

(Note: $E[X]$ is the expected value or mean).

I know that generally $E[N(t)]= \lambda t$, where $t$ is time. Since this is a Poisson process, wouldn't it not matter that $N(1)=3$ since the increments are independent? If so, then would it be correct to claim that $E[N(4)-N(2)|N(1)=3]$= $E[N(4)-N(2)]$=$2 \lambda$?

Comment: The notation $S_n$ is not useful.

Comment: @Did It was used in another part of the question.

Comment: Then let me suggest to avoid copying useless parts of your questions on the site.

Comment: @Did I didn't pay attention to it at the time, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't feel I can contribute any more by writing out an answer, except:

yes you are correct. It follows from independent increment. that $N(4)-N(2)$ is independent of $N(1)-N(0)=N(1)$. therefore, is is just $E[N(4)-N(2)]=2\lambda$

Answer (score -4):

Actually, wouldn't the answer be $2\lambda+3$? $2\lambda$ is the expected occurrences from time $2$ to time $4$ $(N(4)-N(2))$ and you are guaranteed $3$ from the condition.